# How would I implement help on a Java EE web application for end users?

Tags: java, html, css, jakarta-ee

I'm trying to find the best way to add help to a Java EE web application. I am reading that .chm files are obsolete and shouldn't be used due to security issues in Windows. The site will only be accessed on a private LAN through a web browser.

It sounds kind of old school, but I was thinking that I would just write the HTML and have hyperlinks to jump to the section of the page where the relevant content is.

I'm wondering if just a regular old HTML page will work? Is this okay for enterprise? Are there any standards, or software programs that would help with a table of contents and list of help items?

The users will obviously need to be able to have quick and easy access to help, if they have questions on a particular page. Could I implement some type of tool-tips written in Java EE or otherwise that would prompt quicker than an HTML page would load?

Comment: We use an HTML popup for our homepage, which is accessible via a link.

Comment: Thanks Tim. How does it appear on the page? Just a small box?

Comment: It is a popup say two-thirds the width of the screen.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You can have a HELP link throughout your application. When clicked it opens a plain browser window showing the help content. Plain browser window means no navigation buttons, this way users won't be using this window to continue their work which can be problematic. This will force them to simply close the window when they are done with it.

Help content can be plain HTML or dynamic (.jsp) depending on how complex the help structure is. Advantage of jsp is the content can be served dynamically from a database, and you can build the table of contents from server side, so more suited for larger help content.

The help link can be customised depending on what page you're on, so that users are taken directly to the relevant help. This can be done with query strings, for example help.html#abc or help.jsp?topic=abc to take users directly to the abc topic.

In addition to the full-blown help page(s), you could also have inline tooltips for individual fields for example. Add a small question mark icon next to the field label that when hovered or clicked will display a short information about that particular field.

A good example of this tooltip is what you can find next to the CVV field on various credit card payment pages.

Hope that helps.

Comment: In-line tool-tips with question mark that hyperlink/jump to the help.jsp page? Ever done this? :)

Comment: @PeachesToad, I haven't, but if it works for you why not